# Refresh process should run in background, but sub processed need to be synchronous

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, concurrency

I am working on implementing a manual refresh. That refresh process has 3 steps. Each one needs to be completed before the other (synchronous, serial, etc.). All of them need to be done in background so as not to block the UI.

I've tested the 3 methods individually and they all do what they should (get data from server, update db, etc.) but when I uncomment everything and run, the 2nd is starting before the first is done. And I can't figure out how to fix this. I tried `NSInvocationOperation` for the 3 methods and setting `dependencies`. didnt work. Tried `queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1`. didnt work.

The first method calls other methods and over the course of it, calls other things that create separate `thread`s, so is that the issue? When that happens, does it think the operation is done? Is `NSOperation` too complicated? Is there a simpler way just to say "do this and dont do this til its done"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `NSOperationQueue` and multiple `NSOperation` instances, and specifying dependencies between them is the correct approach.

If the operations create other threads and don't wait for them to finish then that would be a problem because the operation would finish and the next operation would start running.

Operations that run a asynchronously should be executed in an `NSOperation` subclass. This subclass needs to return YES from `isConcurrent` To keep the operation alive after the start/main method returns. The operation is complete when `isFinished` is changed to YES (it is observed with KVO so the change notifications must be sent). So, the asynchronous process needs to update and post the appropriate notifications when it has completed. This will terminate the operation and allow the next one to begin.

Comment: thanks for quick response! i sure thought dependency sounded like exactly what i wanted. think i found a possible problem (a lot is inherited code) the method called by the operation to start step 1 then has the line self.refreshOne = [[[RefreshOne alloc] initWithDelegate:self] autorelease]; so it just creates a custom object? Problem is, inside that initWithDelegate, it sets up some variables, then calls getData, THEN has "return self". Inside getData, includes using ASIHTTP to hit server. So it kicks back to init and does return self so the operation thinks its done. do i need custom object?

Comment: ahhh right, okay. yea i might have to do that to get this done. whats the downside again?

Comment: i found out why things were starting before others have ended and have step 1 running correctly, with that fixed, you recommend NSOperation instead of dispatch serial queues right?

Comment: thank you so much for the help! one more question if i can. ive inherited this project and i just dont understand a way around this one part. it seems that using a queue, one thing at a time, only works if none of those tasks create any threads themselves. im sure people have done this or maybe im not thinking of it correctly. if step 3 is dependent on step 2, but step 2 at some point launches a thread, step 2 will finish. is the approach to tell 3 to wait no matter what (ugly semaphore) or rewrite code to just execute since youre already in background?

Comment: Wasn't thinking about the correct solution the other day, `NSOperation` can support asynchronous behaviour, it just isn't very obvious how and I had forgotten. Updated the answer.